# Как здесь срабатывает проверка на истинность?

Tags: java

Только учусь java. Это программка по выводу четных чисел. И почему-то я проверку на истинность понимаю наоборот. Как я мыслю... Например i=5, соответственно остаток по модулю равен 1. И тут проверка на истинность 1!=0, то есть "вопрос 1 не равно 0?" Ответ на этот вопрос - "Да", значит True и проверка на истинность пройдена. Значит цифра 5 должна выводится в консоль, а она не выводится. Подскажите пожалуйста где в моем мышлении ошибка.

```
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int i;

        for (i = 0; i <= 20; i++) {
            if ((i % 2) != 0) continue;
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> вопрос 1 не равно 0?" Ответ на этот вопрос - "Да", значит True и проверка на истинность пройдена. Значит цифра 5 должна выводится в консоль

все верно, кроме последнего предложения. 
у вас код выглядит так

```
if ((i % 2) != 0) continue;
```

соответственно, подставляем 5, получаем (5 % 2 = 1) != 0 ? да, 1 не равно 0, следовательно, идем на следующую итерацию

Comment: То есть я неправильно понимаю как работает инструкция continue? получается что проверку на истинность мы прошли, и инструкция continue  при "Истинности" не продолжает работу цикла с выводом на печать, а прерывает работу цикла и возвращает нас в начало цикла? Я правильно понимаю?

Comment: да, все верно. работа continue в этом и заключается - перейти на следующую итерацию цикла

Answer (score 1):

Вы не учитываете поведение инструкции `continue`, по сути она "бросает" вас на конец цикла

Не на начало, а именно конец - это важно потому что есть постфиксные циклы типа `do-while`, в которых проверка условия цикла выполняется в конце, а не в начале.

Comment: Важное замечание - спасибо)))

Answer (score 0):

Если проверка выдает True, то выполняется continue. Вывод выполняется если проверка выдает False.